# MS Access Form bound to ADO recordset refresh and filter error

Tags: ado

I'm using Access as a front-end to SQL Server and trying to use ADO recordset as a source for Access Form.
I'm able to see records in datasheet view, I can add and edit records on that form.

Now I'm stuck on 2 errors I get when I try to apply text or number filters to ADO recordset bound Form in datasheet view or when I try to refresh Form.

1. If I use the field filter in the Datasheet view I get an error:"Enter a valid value"
2. If i try to refresh Form by using F5 key I get an error: "Data provider could not be initialized"

If I use linked tables to SQL Server and use those tables as record source for the Form none of the problems described occur.

This is the code I use to set forms Recordset:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()


Dim ConnString As String
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset


ConnString= "Provider=sqloledb;Server=xxx; Database=yyyyy; user Id=zzzz; password=uuuu;"

     Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
     cnn.ConnectionString = ConnString
     cnn.Open
     Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "select Field1, Field2, Field3 from dbo.TableA", cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic
Set Me.Recordset = rs

End sub
```

It is also interesting that no matter what cursorType I use (adOpenStatic in this example), I'm always able to edit and add records in the form.

Is it at all possible to use Access functionality (filters, refresh) with ADO recordsets?

Answer (score 0):

Ad. 1 see this https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=sort-filter-access-form-bound-adodb-recordset

Ad. 2 On Form_Error use this:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    Const NO_DATA_SUPPLIER As Integer = 31
    If DataErr = NO_DATA_SUPPLIER Then  
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        'in this line you have to reasign your datasource for form
    End If
End Sub
```